# Как создать листание страниц в Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть класс

```
private class NextPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Log.e("try", "Запущен цикл try!");

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://kinozz.club/licenziya/page/2/")
                    /*.data("query", "Java")*/
                    .userAgent("Chrome")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(6000).get();

            add = doc.select("div.title-short");
            titleList.clear();

            if(!add.isEmpty()) {

                for (Element content : add) {
                    titleList.add(content.text());
                }

            }else {
                Crash();
                finish();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Нужно в строке

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://kinozz.club/licenziya/page/2/")
```

менять номера страниц, то есть 2, 3, 4, и так хотя бы 10. Абсолютно любым способом, лучше конечно массивом, и без новых интентов, то есть обновлять уже существующий новыми данными.

Comment: `for (int i=2; i<=10; i++) {...}`?

Comment: Ну может "http://kinozz.club/licenziya/page/" записать в какую-нибудь переменную вне класса NextPage, допустим LINK, а при нажатии на кнопку перелистывания страницы сделать прибавление счётчика i на один. Переменную LINK соответственно изменить на LINK + i.toString() + "/". Затем вызвать NextPage, в котором будет это: doc = Jsoup.connect(LINK);

Comment: @CookieMnstr я твою мысль понял, возможно прокатит